# Get count of rows returned by a query result set without ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, count

I have my below query which will give me the EmployeeId and the number of times he has logged in to a application

```
SELECT E.[EmployeeId], COUNT(*) LoginCount
FROM tblEmployee E
JOIN tblAccessLog AL ON E.EmployeeId = AL.EmployeeId
WHERE AL.[AccessType] = 212
GROUP BY E.[EmployeeId]
```

I would like to get those employees who logged in more than particular threshold, let me take 100.

```
SELECT E.[EmployeeId], COUNT(*) LoginCount
FROM tblEmployee E
JOIN tblAccessLog AL ON E.EmployeeId = AL.EmployeeId
WHERE AL.[AccessType] = 212
GROUP BY E.[EmployeeId]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
```

Now I would like to get the count returned by the above query, I mean the count of employees who have accesses my site more than 100 times.

I tried `@@ROWCOUNT` and it returns the count of users, but that returns 2 result sets and I am looking if there is a better way instead of using `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use your current query as a sub-query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT E.[EmployeeId], COUNT(*) LoginCount
    FROM tblEmployee E
    JOIN tblAccessLog AL ON E.EmployeeId = AL.EmployeeId
    WHERE AL.[AccessType] = 212
    GROUP BY E.[EmployeeId]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
) X
```

Answer (score 0):

Using windowed `COUNT`:

```
Select E.[EmployeeId], COUNT(*) LoginCount, COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt_of_Employee
FROM tblEmployee E
JOIN tblAccessLog AL ON E.EmployeeId = AL.EmployeeId
WHERE AL.[AccessType] = 212
GROUP BY E.[EmployeeId]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
```